# Connecting to websites takes time on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: browser, connection, ubuntu-18.04

I upgraded to ubuntu 18.04 about a month ago on my MSI 7REX Leopard Pro. Although the system works fine with the usual performance, somehow the *internet is always slow to connect* for the first time AND when I reopen the browser tabs after waking it up from the suspend mode. I need to wait at least 2-3 mins before the webpage starts to load.

I've tried to change the "nameserver" settings in the \etc\resolv.conf from the default like this:

```
#nameserver 127.0.0.53
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
search home
```

the added commands are on line2 and line3 (the rest were default). But it didn't change anything so I reverted back.

This problem is not browser specific (I use firefox and chrome). I've tried to use Cinnamon but that too didn't solve the issue.  Any solution?